# Setting opacity value of a button with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

I'm trying to set a button so everytime the user clicks on it, its opacity rises until it reaches 1. I got this but this only works with the first click. The next clicks are registered but don't add up to the opacity.

```
document.getElementById('buttonHello').style.opacity+=0.1;
```

Thanks

edit: Hello, I need help please.

Comment: Never mind I used another approach, but I'm still curious, is opacity a String or what?

Comment: `alert(typeof document.getElementById('buttonHello').style.opacity)`  will answer that question.

Comment: you need to use `window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(prop)`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a pen to illustrate how to do this (reverting opacity back to 0.1 after it reaches 1):

http://codepen.io/MisterGrumpyPants/pen/Gofhd

The key was this JS:

```
var button = document.getElementById('buttonHello');

var getOpacity = function(el) {
  return el.style.opacity;
}

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var currentOpacity = parseFloat(getOpacity(button));
  var newOpacity = (currentOpacity < 0.9) ? currentOpacity + 0.1 : 0.1;
  button.style.opacity = newOpacity;
});
```

Maybe what you needed to know about was the `parseFloat()` part?

**UPDATE: getComputedStyle or element.style?**

I think you would use `getComputedStyle` if you need to get your `opacity` value from a stylesheet, as opposed to an inline style (notice I started with an inline value in my codepen). But once you're setting inline styles with JS, I think you may as well be using `element.style.opacity`. (In fact, I ran across this [jsPerf test suggesting that `.style` is significantly faster than `getComputedStyle`](http://jsperf.com/getcomputedstyle-vs-style-vs-css/2).)

Answer (score 0):

do this **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/A7eMh/

```
function ch() {
var x=getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('buttonHello')).getPropertyValue('opacity');
x=(x*1)+.1;
document.getElementById('buttonHello').style.opacity=x;
}
```